# FastAPI 422 Unprocessable Entity - how to update many rows at once?

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

I want to update all rows in the *values table* that meet a condition based on a customer id and a group. I used the join statement to select all products that belong to the specific group. The table is set as

```
class Values(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'values'
    
    customer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('customer.customer_id'), primary_key=True, ullable=False) 
    product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('product.product_id'), primary_key = True, nullable= False) 
    quantity = Column(Numeric)
```

```
@router.put('/{customer_id}/{group}')
def update_values(customer_id: int, group:str, updated: schemas.Quantity, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):  
    sub_query = db.query(models.Values, models.Product.group).join(models.Product, models.Product.product_id == models.Values.product_id).filter(models.Values.customer_id==customer_id, models.Product.group==group).subquery()
    main_query = db.query(models.Values).filter(models.Values.product_id.in_(sub_query))
    

      
    main_query.update({models.Values.quantity: updated.item_value}, synchronize_session=False)

    db.commit()

    return main_query.all()
```

My schema is

```
class Quantity(BaseModel):
    item_value: float
```

I get the error message 422 Unprocessable Entity.

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "path",
        "product_id"
      ],
      "msg": "value is not a valid integer",
      "type": "type_error.integer"
    }
  ]
}
```

Could someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: 422 unprocessable entity means that you're missing some of the required information defined in the controller - it does not mean that the code inside the controller is doing something (the view is never invoked, since required information is missing). The body of the 422 error will contain information about _what_ is missing, and since you haven't included the request you're making, it's impossible to say what you're not sending that FastAPI expects.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh, I have added the details about the error. But I don't understand it.

Comment: You're matching a route that has `{product_id}` defined that maps to an integer, but you're not submitting an integer in the location where it expects it. From the defined route in your code you have included, it seems like you have multiple routes defined that match the same path (for example both a route with `{customer_id}` and one with `{product_id}` on the root level). Since you haven't included any code with `product_id` in the path set, it's hard to say anything else.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you! Now I could see what I was doing wrong.